# How to remove spikes from grid in SAGA GIS?

Tags: raster, interpolation, saga, filter

I tried to get a grid by interpolating LAS file using Ordinary Kriging. But the product grid has many pixels which values strongly stands out from average surface - I mean one pixel sinks nad spikes. I know that sinks can be easily filled with preprocessing modules, but I found removing spikes more complicated.
Is there any automated way to remove them? For instance a module which could get rid of pixels with values that stands out from their neighborhood?

Comment: Perhaps this [post](http://dominoc925.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/remove-noisy-spikes-from-lidar-data.html) might help?

Answer (score 2):

You can try Grid – Filter→DTM Filter (slope-based). There is a very clear instruction in document **"pc_processing_with_saga.pdf"** by mr. Volker Wichmann, that could help you. Link below :

[https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/GEOSTAT_2012/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/GEOSTAT_2012/pc_processing_with_saga.pdf/download)

It's on page 26, but in your case it's worth to read all.